# jQuery and IE7 cross-browser bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

```
$("body").delegate('area[id=area_kontakt]','mouseover mouseleave', function(e){
if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
    $("#kontakt_tip").css('display','block');
} else {
    $("#kontakt_tip").css('display','none');
}
});
```

Why this code doesn't work in IE7? In IE8, FF, Ch everything is OK. Any help?

Regards.

Comment: Try changing `'area[id=area_kontakt]'` to `'area[id="area_kontakt"]'` -- The IE is really pendantic sometimes.

Comment: Why not use `#area_kontakt` instead of an explicit `id` attribute selector?

Comment: insted of area[id=area_kontakt], why can't we use like this "#area_kontakt"? This is not solution, just doubt... r u using multiple ids with same name?

Comment: No. The 'area_kontakt' element is unique!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having examined your site, I've found the cause of the problem.

Nobody could have worked this out without seeing the site, because the problem had nothing to do with the code you've provided in your question.

In `functions.js`, you have this a few times (I've trimmed it down):

```js
xxx.modal({
    //..
    top: 50, //<---
    /*onOpen: function (xxx) {
        //..
    }*/
});
```

The problem is that trailing comma; [it breaks IE7 and older](http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/).

[image]

Comment: ..and if you don't have multiple elements with the same `id`, just ignore me :)

Comment: Oh well. Do you have a live page demonstrating the problem? Or can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's because IE7 doesn't support atrribute selectors: `[id=area_kontakt]`, You'll have to use a class name/Id name for IE7 to support it inside your jQuery.